# Можно ли настроить AWS SQS так чтобы событие из топика было считано всеми нодами подключенные к топику

Tags: amazon-web-services

Нужно как то передать событие которое было бы считано всеми нодами сервиса, можно ли это сделать с помощью SQS?

Comment: передавайте событие SQS->SNS, и из SNS уже делайте мультикаст на всех подписчиков.

Comment: @tym32167 Я вижу здесь в ответе про разницу между SQS и SNS то что SNS удаляет сообщение как только кому то было доставлено

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50851239/4380432

Comment: Sqs копит сообщения и ждёт, когда их кто то заберет. Одно сообщение обычно достаётся одному пполучателю . То есть будет очередь и сто получателей, сообщение достанется только одному из них. В этом прикол очереди. Sns наоборот, не ждёт ничего, пришло сообщение - в него - sns просто тупо всем подписчикам его разошлёт и все. Если ты подписан - получишь каждое сообщение от sns, но sns не хранит сообщения, просто высылает.

Comment: Сценарий, который ты описываешь, хорошо ложится на Кафку. И Кафка тоже есть в AWS https://aws.amazon.com/msk/

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov нужно смотреть по нагрузке и конкретному use-case, но зачастую Кафка это слишком и по возможностям кафки и по стоимости. Из вопроса автора не понятно какую проблему необходимо решить. Только условие, чтобы одно сообщение получило несколько consumers(подписчиков?). Следуя Well-Architected Framework(https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected) SNS + SQS было бы наименее затратное(в том числе по разработке) решение с приличной производительностью. Если не SNS + SQS тогда уж лучше посмотреть в сторону Kinesis

Answer (score 1):

@tym32167 думал в правильном направлении. С помощью SNS -> SQS можно реализовать [сценарий Fanout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-common-scenarios.html). Суть в том, чтобы оригинальное сообщение отправлять в SNS topic, на который будут подписаны несколько SQS queues. Таким образом все очереди могут получить одно и то же сообщение. То есть, чтобы решить вашу проблему, вам нужен SNS Topic(куда producer будет отправлять сообщение) и SQS queue для каждого сервиса, чтобы получить это сообщение.

На диаграмме все выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это вообщем-то довольно распространенный сценарий.